# How to choose from two different results of NIntegrate?

Tags: numerical-integration

Consider the following two integrals:

```
I1=NIntegrate[Exp[-(Exp[y2]+y0)x3] Exp[-(y0+y1+1)x2] Exp[-(Exp[y3]+y1)x1] ,{x1,0,\[Infinity]},{x2,0,\[Infinity]},{x3,0,\[Infinity]},{y0,0,\[Infinity]},{y1,0,\[Infinity]},{y2,0,\[Infinity]},{y3,0,\[Infinity]}]

I2=NIntegrate[(Exp[y2] + y0)^(-1)  (y0 + y1 + 1)^(-1) (Exp[y3] + 
 y1)^(-1) , {y0, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y1, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y2, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y3, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

I2 results by just analytically integrating over x1, x2, and x3 in I1. But I1 give the result 6.75 and I2 gives 7.30. Both result in error messages regarding slow convergence. I would greatly appreciate any ideas how to improve evaluation of these kinds of integrals. I have tried various options regarding accuracy, method of evaluation, number of iterations etc, but without any luck in resolving the issue.

Comment: In the first integral, the integrand doesn't depend on x1, so I1 must be infinite!

Comment: Thanks Urlich, I corrected it

Answer (score 2):

The following two integrations seem to agree on the result being $\approx 7.3$.
Note the big difference in the timings.

```
In[22]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 I1 = NIntegrate[
   Exp[-(Exp[y2] + y0) x3] Exp[-(y0 + y1 + 1) x2] Exp[-(Exp[y3] + 
         y1) x1], {x1, 0, \[Infinity]}, {x2, 0, \[Infinity]}, {x3, 
    0, \[Infinity]}, {y0, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y1, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y2, 
    0, \[Infinity]}, {y3, 0, \[Infinity]}, MinRecursion -> 2, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000, 
     "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, "SingularityHandler" -> None}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 4]
 ]

NIntegrate::slwcon...
NIntegrate::eincr...

Out[22]= {1697.16, 7.29473}


In[23]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 I2 = NIntegrate[(Exp[y2] + y0)^(-1) (y0 + y1 + 1)^(-1) (Exp[y3] + 
       y1)^(-1), {y0, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y1, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y2, 
    0, \[Infinity]}, {y3, 0, \[Infinity]}, MinRecursion -> 2, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000, 
     "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, "SingularityHandler" -> None}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 2]
 ]

Out[23]= {0.314175, 7.30738}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I voted your answer, but a message appeared saying that since I am a new user of the site, the vote is recorded but not displayed.
I originally used MaxErrorIncreases->10000. When I used your value of 100000, I get I1=7.13
Further convergence to I2=7.30, you get by using the two options that I haven’t used: “SymbolicProcessing”->0 and “SingularityHandler”->None. I don’t understand why would user need to disable some built-in functions of NIntegrate (to get the better result), but you completely answered the original question that I posed.

Comment: Thanks. The combination(s) of symbolic processing, singularity handing, and convergence heuristics is always going to bring some tradeoffs. High dimensional integration can be very slow and with some non-intuitive behavior. Generally the default option values produce good results, but with high dimensional numerical integration it is much easier to get into hard to compute computations that in turn make the analysis of the results much harder.

Comment: OK thank you it is helpful to know

Answer (score 1):

With your corrections you get

```
I1 = NIntegrate[
Exp[-(Exp[y2] + y0) x3] Exp[-(y0 + y1 + 
     1) x2] Exp[-(Exp[y3] + y1) x1], {x1, 0, \[Infinity]}, {x2, 
0, \[Infinity]}, {x3, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y0, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y1, 
0, \[Infinity]}, {y2, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y3, 0, \[Infinity]} 
]

I2 = NIntegrate[
int2 = (Exp[y2] + y0)^(-1) (y0 + y1 + 1)^(-1) (Exp[y3] + 
   y1)^(-1), {y0, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y1, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y2, 
0, \[Infinity]}, {y3, 0, \[Infinity]}
]
```

the integrals are

```
I1=6.75834
I2=7.30568
```

but I don't know which result is more trustable!

But you can elaborate the integral a little bit further:

If you substitute the parameters y2,y3 by z2=Exp[-y2], z3=Exp[-y3] you can solve the integrals concerning z2,z3 analytical and you'll get a remaining Integral 
in the space y0,y1

```
NIntegrate[Log[1 + y0]/y0 Log[1 + y1]/y1)/ (1 + y0 + y1)   , {y0,0,\[Infinity]}, {y1, 0, \[Infinity]} ]

7.30568
```

which numerically evaluates to I2!

Comment: Thank you Urlich; your (y0/Log[1+y0]) should be to the power (-1) and analogously for the y1 term. This gives the same result for I2 of 7.30. Therefore the difference between I1 and I2 remains.

Comment: I edited my answer. I2 seems to me more trustable! Compared with I1( 7 dimensional integral!) only two remaining dimensions in the last evaluation

Comment: My primary interest is whether there are options in NIntegrate that one can use so that both I1 and I2 give the same result. Thank you for your discussion.

Comment: In the help of NIntegrate you'll find this information "For low-dimensional integrals, the default setting for PrecisionGoal is related to WorkingPrecision. For high-dimensional integrals, it is typically taken to be a fixed value, usually 2." Obviously the reduction of the dimension of the integrals is the right way.

Comment: You are right in what you said. My question, however, is an example where it is obvious that the two integrals (I1 and I2) are the same, but numerical results are different. 
If starting from the same equations, one arrives by various techniques at two expressions for multiple integrals, it is needed to check that the results agree. The approach leading to lower dimensional integral could be in error.

Comment: Your approach with analytical integration by parts in several dimensions is straight forward without 'error' and has main advantages compared to the stricly numerical version.  Perhaps a look in the help of NIntegrate "The Uncertainties of Numerical Mathematics" will give you some hints.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It is always better to proceed analytically when possible. In instances where that cannot be done it is needed to explore available options in the numerical procedures that improve the results.